# The normal to the curve $y=2x^2-x+3$ at the point $P(1,4)$ meets at the curve again at the point $Q$. What is the $x$- coordinate of $Q$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The normal to the curve $y=2x^2-x+3$ at the point $P(1,4)$ meets at the curve again at the point $Q$. What is the $x$- coordinate of $Q$?

---

Please answer as soon as possible ! 
$(-4/7), -1, 0$ are wrong answers. Accept them if you find anything!

Comment: What's the rush? Math is eternal! Anyway, what do you know about normals to a curve? Do you know anything about the slope of such a normal?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig There is a strange symbol also: .

Comment: @Sebastiano  While it looks like the Hindu greeting namaste, it may mean please or I implore you.  Then again, I am just speculating based on the context.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative is $4x-1$. Therefore the derivate at that point is 3. From that, the normal slope is $-\frac{1}{3}$ We can form a line from this: $y-4=-\frac{1}{3}(x-1)$ This simplifies to $y=-\frac{x}{3}+\frac{13}{3}$. So we need $$2x^2-x+3=-\frac{x}{3}+\frac{13}{3}$$ From this:$$2x^2-\frac{2x}{3}-\frac{4}{3}$$After multiplying by 3, which preserves the roots:$$6x^2-2x-4$$ Which factors to, $(6x+4)(x-1)$. This makes sense because the one root is at one, the point, and the other is at $x=-\frac{4}{6}=-\frac{2}{3}$. This is your answer.

Comment: I think that should be $-4/6$.

Comment: @martycohen sorry, I was not paying attention while typing.

Comment: Yup. Sign errors are one of my common mistakes.

Comment: Good. Now OP can just copy down everything you've written, and hand it in as his own work, without understanding any of it.